# CSS apply to all inside div but skip first child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i'm a beginner and have a question.

The goal : Render a bar under all ".title-title" classes NOT not the first one.

I made that and it's working great but for the purpose of learning I would like to see a better/one line/pro solution maybe ?

Thanks for your advices.

```css
#second .title-title:after,
#third .title-title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

/* Part of my own external bootstrap rip off LUL */
.py-ta-c {
  text-align: center;
}

.py-mb-m {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">First</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Exclude me</h4>
</div>

<div id="second" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">Second</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

<div id="third" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">Third</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

<!-- AND SO ON -->
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply to all and remove it from the first one:

```css
/* All the titles */
.title-title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
/* We remove from the first one*/
#first .title-title:after {
  display:none;
}

/* Part of my own external bootstrap rip off LUL */
.py-ta-c {
  text-align: center;
}

.py-mb-m {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">First</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Exclude me</h4>
</div>

<div id="second" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">Second</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

<div id="third" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">Third</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

<!-- AND SO ON -->
```

Or use [`not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) selector:

```css
/* Select all the divs but not the one with ID first*/
div:not(#first) .title-title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
/* OR
Select all the divs but not the first child
div:not(:first-child) .title-title:after { }
*/


/* Part of my own external bootstrap rip off LUL */
.py-ta-c {
  text-align: center;
}

.py-mb-m {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">First</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Exclude me</h4>
</div>

<div id="second" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">Second</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

<div id="third" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">Third</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

<!-- AND SO ON -->
```

Another one with [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)/[`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) (*but be careful when the HTML structure changes*):

```css
/* This will select 2nd,3rd,4th .. */
div:nth-child(n+2) .title-title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
/* OR 
div:nth-of-type(n+2) .title-title:after { }

*/


/* Part of my own external bootstrap rip off LUL */
.py-ta-c {
  text-align: center;
}
.py-mb-m {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">First</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Exclude me</h4>
</div>

<div id="second" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">Second</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

<div id="third" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
 <h2 class="title-title">Third</h2>
 <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

<!-- AND SO ON -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `:not(:first-child)` on the parent if you don't want to use any id:

```
div:not(:first-child) .title-title::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper div h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
.wrapper div:first-child h2:after{
  display:none
}

/* Part of my own external bootstrap rip off LUL */
.py-ta-c {
  text-align: center;
}

.py-mb-m {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div id="first" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
    <h2 class="title-title">First</h2>
    <h4 class="title-subtitle">Exclude me</h4>
</div>

<div id="second" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
    <h2 class="title-title">Second</h2>
    <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

<div id="third" class="py-ta-c py-mb-m">
    <h2 class="title-title">Third</h2>
    <h4 class="title-subtitle">Include me</h4>
</div>

</div>
<!-- AND SO ON -->
```